# Preventing fluid/responsive divs from floating

Tags: html, navigation, responsive-design, css-float, fluid-layout

I have read many answers on here over the past two weeks, but can't seem to find the right solution to my problem. Is anyone able to help?

I am trying to build my first responsive website, and am using Dreamweaver's fluid template. However, I cannot prevent my bottom-right aligned navigation from overlapping over my top logo and tagline div layers, and cannot make my navigation table to shrink when viewed on mobiles?

I have one gridContainer with three 800px wide divs on top of each other (these shrink to fit when viewed on smaller portals):
Div id: header
Div id: logo and
Div id: tag

Beneath this, I have three left floating narrower divs (60% wide)  (these shrink to fit when viewed on smaller portals):
Div id: body
Div id: border and
Div id: bookus

Finally, one navigation div (30% wide):
Div id: contact

This navigation div is a table of rollover images that are of a stack of crates, where each crate is a link. As such, I need this to remain at the bottom of a browser window no matter how big it is opened to, but also to not overlap over the Logo and Tag div, if the window is resized to smaller.   (I'm unable to make it shrink proportionally for smaller portals)

Here is my CSS (my apologies, I am not sure how much information is needed):

```
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 84.9333%;
min-height: 600px;
padding-left: 3.0333%;
padding-right: 3.0333%;
padding-top: 3.0333%;
padding-bottom: 0;
top: 10%;
}

#header {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 15%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 60%;
height: auto;
display: block;

}

#logo {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 10%;
width: 60%;
height: auto;
display: block;

}

#tag {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 60%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

#body {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#border {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#bookus {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#contact {
clear: both;
float: right;
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 60%;
margin-bottom: 0;
width: 30%;
height: auto;
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
min-height: 158px;
min-width: 132px;
table-layout:auto;
}


/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer {
width: 86.8%;
min-height: 800px;
max-height: 100%;
padding-left: 3.1%;
padding-right: 3.1%;
padding-top: 3.1%;
padding-bottom: 0;
top: 10%;
}

#header {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 15%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 80%;
height: auto;
display: block;

}

#logo {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
width: 80%;
height: auto;
display: block;

}

#tag {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 5px;
width: 80%;
height: auto;   
display: block;
}

#body {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#border {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#bookus {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#contact {
clear: both;
float: right;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 60%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0;
width: 30%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
min-height: 158px;
min-width: 132px;
table-layout:auto;

}

}


/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) { 

.gridcontainer {
width: 84%;
max-width: 800px;
min-height: 800px;
max-height: 1180px;
padding-left: 3%;
padding-right: 3%;
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
top: 10%;
}

#header {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 15%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
display: block;

}

#logo {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;

}

#tag {
clear: both;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
display: block;
}

#body {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#border {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#bookus {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 60%;
display: block;
}

#contact {
clear: both;
float: right;
margin-right: 30%;
margin-left: 50%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0;
width: 30%;
height: 30%;
min-height: 158px;
min-width: 132px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
table-layout:auto;
}

}
```

Here is my html source code for the navigation table, (do I need to add more than this?):

```
<div class="contact" id="contact" align="right">
<table width="100%" height="100%"border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position:absolute; bottom:0;height:auto; width:auto; max-width:265px; max-height:296px;">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="mailto:email@url.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_EMAIL.png" alt="email us" name="email" width="265" height="86" id="email" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('email','','00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_EMAILO.png',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" border="0" align="absbottom" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:265px; max-height:86px;"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="tel:+123-456-7890" target="_blank"><img src="00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_CALL.png" alt="call us" name="call" width="265" height="70" id="call" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('call','','00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_CALLO.png',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" border="0" align="absbottom" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:265px; max-height:70px;"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://www.url.com/" target="_blank"><img src="00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_FB.png" alt="like us" name="fb" width="265" height="70" id="facebook" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('facebook','','00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_FBO.png',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" border="0" align="absbottom" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:265px; max-height:70px;"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=twitterid" target="_blank"><img src="00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_TWEET.png" alt="mention us" name="tweet" width="265" height="70" lowsrc="00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_EMAILO.png" id="tweet" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('tweet','','00_assets/buttons/00_BUTTONS_TWEETO.png',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" border="0" align="absbottom" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:265px; max-height:70px;"></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you so much, in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is quite difficult to understand the problem simply reading your description of it.. there are some sites (jsfiddle, jsbin, codepen) that can be used to reproduce the issue you are having. Please consider making an online example of your problem, it will be much easier to help you

Comment: Thank you skip405. I have just tried to use jsfiddle, jsbin and codepen, but I don't know how to upload the images for my website on to it to be able to view the issue?  Somehow I seem to have fixed the issue of making the navigation shrink for smaller portals, however, I still have the issue where the bottom side navigation div (id contacts) overlaps the logo and tagline divs at certain sizes, and that this div doesn't always remain at the bottom.

Comment: should I post the whole html? would this help? or is there something in particular you would need from the code?

Comment: Actually I've loaded it here, if this helps? http://hooboo.co.uk/999_ttbb/index.html